# Mysql prevent union based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement, union

I'd like to trigger a `union` depending on a condition:

```
set @a := 0;

select @a := 1, b.name from B b
UNION
select 0, c.name from C c
```

To output like:

```
set @a := 0;

select @a := 1, b.name from B b
if(@a > 0, UNION select 0, c.name from C c, '');
```

So I can save the second select if the first one already return rows. Thing is that those queries are heavy and have many joins, so I want to execute them only if necessary.

Since this work:

```
select b.name from B b where if(true, b.name = 'example', '')
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks.

ssedano

Answer (score 2):

You want to select all rows from B.  If there are none, then you want the rows from C.  You can probably fiddle with conditional logic to do this.  You can also do it with a SQL query:

```
select 1 as which, name
from B union all
select 0 as which, name
from C
where not exists (select 1 from B limit 1)
```

Comment: Thing is that the first query has some joins and legacy stuff which makes it slow. I was wondering if it was possible at all to save issuing more than one select

Comment: If you don't want to execute the queries, then you need conditional logic, possibly with temporary tables.